# How do I include a partial from a directory above a wordpress theme directory?

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming, directory-structure

I have 3 themes set up right now and I need them all to inherit partials from the same source in order to update all three themes at the exact same time when I change any of those partials.

I'm seeing that

```
include("../../../includes/vital/partial.php");
```

doesn't work from within single.php or any other other theme template file. The error I get is:

> Warning: include(): Failed opening '../../../includes/vital/partial.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.8/lib/php') in /Users/insertusername/Documents/Code/Projects/wordpress/wordpress-1/wp-content/themes/flowerz-mobile/single.php on line 7

How can I make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the partial located? What folder?

Comment: it's located at wordpress_root /includes/vital/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Wordpress loads all based on the main `index.php` the code below worked for me in every theme.

```
include("includes/vital/partial.php");
```

that`s right, without any `../` at the begining.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to use some kind of absolute path API function like get_bloginfo('wpurl')..etc and similar.